# Controlling Picklist Value is not showing up on the email template

Tags: email-template, dependent-picklist

I have a controlling picklist, which values are not showing up in the email template when i use the test of sending template, but the dependent picklist value is showing up, i do not know, where to check for to have it visible.
I tried to set up a new picklist as a controlling one and a new picklist as dependent and both are showing up, so the template is fine, what else can be the problem here?

Comment: This appears to be some sort of limitation. Email templates properly render the use of picklist fields, but no when they're within formulas. I recommend using a formula field to capture the text value of the picklist field